# define map<ivec3, my_custom_class*>

Tags: c++, dictionary, operator-overloading, glm-math

I am trying to define a map that has the key `glm::ivec3` and the value `Chunk*` which is a class I created:

Main.cpp looks like this:

```
#include <map>
#include <Chunk.h>

std::map<glm::ivec3, Chunk*> chunks;
```

Chunk.h looks like this:

```
class Chunk {
public:

    Chunk(glm::mat4 transform, glm::ivec3 position) :
        transform(transform), position(position)
    {
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
    }


    Chunk(int x, int y) : _x(x), _y(y) {}
    ~Chunk() {}

    bool operator<(const Chunk& other) const {
        return (_x < other._x) || (!(other._x < _x) && (_y < other._y));
    }

    // ...

private:
    int _x, _y;
    unsigned int VBO, VAO, EBO;

    // ...
};
```

But I keep getting this error`:

> binary '<': 'const _Ty' does not define this operator or a conversion
> to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

How can I solve this problem? Thank you for your time!

Comment: `operator<` has to exist for the key which is `ivec3`

Comment: @ChrisMM what does that exactly means? Add the `operator<` for `ivec3` instead of `Chunk`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yes, you need to define an `operator<` for `ivec` (or provide a function for the `map`'s `Compare` template parameter) since that is the key type being used for the `map`.  The map won't use your `Chunk::operator<` at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docs: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

> std::map is a sorted associative container that contains key-value
> pairs with unique keys. Keys are sorted by using the comparison
> function Compare

If you don't provide a `Compare` function (to compare keys, so keys are sorted so as to  a determinated key can be quickly found by map code) then the usual (or overloaded) `<` is used.

It happens that `glm::ivec3` does not implement '`<`' overload, and then the compiler complains.

You can use a class on your own, derived from `glm::ivec3` that implements `<` comparator. Or provide your own `Compare` to std::map ctor.

Here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map you have an example where **class** 'PointCmp' is used as "Compare" parameter.

Comment: Compare needs to be a template parameter,

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and also for the example. Everything is clear now and it's working!